# Convert multichannel image into pixelwise pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, image, dataframe

If you have a multiband image of, say, dimensions 1024 * 1024 * 200 (columns * lines * bands) and want to convert that to a pandas dataframe of the form:

```
            Band    Value
1           1       0.14
2           1       1.18
3           1       2.56
.
.
.
209715198   200     1.01
209715199   200     1.15
209715200   200     2.00
```

So basically all pixels in sequential form, with the band number (or wavelength) and the pixel value as columns.

Is there a clever and efficient way of doing this without a lot of loops, appending to arrays and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer

You can do it with numpy. I'll try my best to walk you through it below. First you need the input images in a 3D numpy array. I'm just going to use a randomly generated small one for illustration. This is the full code, with an explanation below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

images = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,5,5))
z, y, x = images.shape ## 2, 5, 5 (200, 1024, 1024 for your example)
arr = np.column_stack((np.repeat(np.arange(z),y*x), images.ravel()))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['Bands', 'Value'])
```

#### Explanation

The `images` output array looks like this (basically 2 images at 5x5 pixels):

```
[[[5 2 3 6 2]
  [6 1 6 3 2]
  [8 3 2 2 1]
  [5 1 2 6 0]
  [3 4 7 0 2]]

 [[1 7 0 7 3]
  [7 4 5 4 3]
  [1 5 4 7 4]
  [2 0 2 7 2]
  [7 0 1 6 7]]]
```

The next step is to use `np.ravel()` to flatten it. Which will output your required Value column:

```py
#images.ravel()
[5 2 3 6 2 6 1 6 3 2 8 3 2 2 1 5 1 2 6 0 3 4 7 0 2 1 7 0 7 3 7 4 5 4 3 1 5
 4 7 4 2 0 2 7 2 7 0 1 6 7]
```

To create the band column, you need to repeat the z value for an array, x*y times. You can do this with `np.repeat()` and `np.arange()`. Which gives you a 1D array:

```py
#(np.repeat(np.arange(z),y*x))
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

This is the required Band column. To combine, them use `np.column_stack()` and then turn it into a dataframe. All of the above steps combined. Would be:

```
arr = np.column_stack((np.repeat(np.arange(z),y*x), images.ravel()))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['Bands', 'Value'])
```

Which will output:

```py
     Bands  Value
0       0      5
1       0      2
2       0      3
3       0      6
4       0      2
5       0      6
6       0      1
7       0      6
8       0      3
9       0      2
10      0      8
11      0      3
12      0      2
13      0      2
14      0      1
15      0      5
16      0      1
17      0      2
18      0      6
19      0      0
20      0      3
21      0      4
22      0      7
23      0      0
24      0      2
25      1      1
26      1      7
27      1      0
...
```

As required. I hope this at least gets you moving in the right direction.